# When I hover over a button, it is bringing that button to the front

Tags: java, swing, object, jbutton

I have a board of Hexagons that were each a bigger rectangle.

```
g.setColor(getBackground());
g.fillPolygon(hexagon);
g.setColor(getForeground());
g.drawPolygon(hexagon);
```

Whenever each hexagon is hovered over, the entire rectangle is brought to the front, resulting in a white rectangle appearing around the edge overlapping other hexagons.
http://prntscr.com/bfiixt <-- example of the problem.

How can I make this background transparent so I don't have thew problem, or how could I stop the button being brought to the front?
Thanks.

```
FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        Rectangle viewR = getBounds();
        Rectangle iconR = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle textR = new Rectangle();

        SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(this,  fm, getText(), null, SwingUtilities.CENTER,
                SwingUtilities.CENTER, SwingUtilities.BOTTOM, SwingUtilities.CENTER, viewR, iconR, textR, 0);

        Point location = getLocation();
        g.drawString(getText(), textR.x - location.x, textR.y - location.y + fm.getAscent());
```

Comment: Any code to help us?

Comment: @svasa I have edited this and added some code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding this code:

```
btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btn.setFocusPainted(false);
btn.setBorderPainted(false);
```

For others having this problem, this fixed it by changing anything outside of the hexagon inside the object to transparent.